# Update one specific row where same employee id has multiple entries in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to sql and stuck in duplicate entries update issue, any help would be greatly appreciated.
I have a table call employee history, it has empid, roleid, rolestartdate, roleenddate columns.
In the table there are multiple entries for one empid based on role assignment and unassignment.
I need to update only one empid row based on below condition.
Select one empid row where rolestartdate is Max date, if it returns more than one row, check roleid columns and filter based on Max roleid.
It should also return those empid rows which has only one entry. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Row_Number` window function.

```
;with cte as
(
select *, 
       Rn = row_number()over(partition by empid order by rolestartdate desc, roleid desc) 
from EmployeeHistory
)
/* 
--To check the records which will be updated
Select * from cte where Rn = 1
*/
update cte 
   set update_column = 'whatever value'
   where Rn = 1
```

Comment: Perfect!! you nailed it. Thank you so much.